# Large Number of Small Files in mapr

Tags: performance, file, hadoop, metadata, mapr

Hi Does MapR support large number(4 Million) of small files (Each 20KB) How well can it manage metadata of these files? If I want to run a mapreduce which parses each of these files, what performance can I expect out of a 5 node (Each node : 32GB RAM,8 Core) cluster. What are the suggestions to improve the performance?

Answer (score 1):

This question was asked on answers.mapr.com as well, and it was answered there. Please see http://answers.mapr.com/questions/6755/large-no-of-small-files.html